# Link to documents from several nodes

Tags: feeds

What would be the best way to set up several nodes so that some of the content is linked to a single document stored on the server? 
For example, I want a document that has some official rules on it and display it on several pages by only editing the source document.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. Questions about the best method are generally not constructive. In your case, it is also not clear what you mean by, "only editing the source document." You could add the document link to every node, or show a block containing a link. Which method is preferable depends from what you want to do; both methods have pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a common piece of content on all the pages, you can  create a block with the common content, and display that block in the content region of the required pages.

Just go to */admin/structure/block* and position the block before or after the **Main page content** block, and set it to only display on the required pages.